# Parse error [{{}}] OR using sanitaizing unsafe url

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 8 and I need to render photos from an API. 
This is where I try to load the images.

```
<img [src]="{{ items[i].urlToImage }}" alt="">
```

I have tried also without the [] around src.

When I use the version WITH the [] I get parse error [{{}}] when I take the off I am getting sanitaizing unsafe URL warning and below I am requested to use property binding->[].
In the component I do use sanitaizer.

```
      urlToImage: this.sanitaizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
                  (ret["articles"][i]["urlToImage"]).toString()
```

I am getting the correct url from the return method (checked in console)

Comment: It's just `[src]="items[i].urlToImage"`. Every time you have `[...]="..."`, the value is an Angular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just use without interpolation `{{}}`:

```
<img [src]="items[i].urlToImage" alt="">
```

OR with interpolation:

```
<img src="{{ items[i].urlToImage }}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Data Binding and property binding together which is not supported in angular. 
Use any one of it.

```
<img [src]="items[i].urlToImage" alt="">
```

OR

```
<img src="{{items[i].urlToImage}}" alt="">
```

Note the best way is to use property binding when working with HTML Attributes using `[]`

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, I've tried both and I get unsafe sanitaizing URL, however I do add it to the safe url.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned - [String interpolation](https://www.javatpoint.com/angular-7-string-interpolation) in angular works without brackets. The brackets `[]` are for property binding - it expects an expression.

As for your sanitizing issue, for resources such is images you should use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` without `toString()` in the end since you want your `[src]` to be `SafeResourceUrl` and not a string.

Template:

`<img [src]="items[i].urlToImage" alt="">`

Typescript:

```
urlToImage: this.sanitaizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
                  (ret["articles"][i]["urlToImage"]);
```